# List of divisors of an integer n (Haskell)

Tags: performance, haskell, primes, factors, factorization

I currently have the following function to get the divisors of an integer:

```
-- All divisors of a number
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors 1 = [1]
divisors n = firstHalf ++ secondHalf
    where firstHalf = filter (divides n) (candidates n)
          secondHalf = filter (\d -> n `div` d /= d) (map (n `div`) (reverse firstHalf))
          candidates n = takeWhile (\d -> d * d <= n) [1..n]
```

I ended up adding the `filter` to `secondHalf` because a divisor was repeating when `n` is a square of a prime number. This seems like a very inefficient way to solve this problem.

So I have two questions: How do I measure if this really is a bottle neck in my algorithm? And if it is, how do I go about finding a better way to avoid repetitions when `n` is a square of a prime?

Answer (score 2):

To mesure where the bottleneck is, put the three auxiliary definitions (firstHalf, secondHalf, candidates) at the top level, and run your code with the profiler on: `ghc -prof --make divisors.hs` `./divisors 100 +RTS -p -RTS`

Also, you know that the biggest candidate is `sqrt n`, so instead of doing that many multiplications `d*d`, just consider `[1..floor (sqrt n)]`

For better algorithms, you should take a maths book, for it's not a haskell related question… Things you can consider: if "a divides b", then for all divisor d of a, d divides b as well.
You'll want to use memoization or dynamic programming to avoid checking multiple times if a given d divides b (for example, if 15 and 27 divide b, then you need to mathematically check only once that 3 divides b. The other times, you just see if 3 is in your table of divisors of b).

Answer (score 1):

You needn't test *all* the elements of reversed second half. You know that if the square root is present, it is the head element there:

```
          secondHalf = let (r:ds) = [n `div` d | d <- reverse firstHalf]
                       in [r | n `div` r /= r] ++ ds
```

This assumes `n` is positive.

A simpler way to handle the sqrt of a number differently is to handle it *separately*:

```hs
divs n = 
  let 
    r = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n 
    (a,b) = unzip $ (1,n) : [(d, q) | d<-[2..r-1], let (q,r)=quotRem n d, r==0]
  in
    if r*r==n
      then a ++ r : reverse b
      else a ++ reverse b
```

That way we get the second half for free, as a part of producing the first half.

But this could hardly be a bottleneck in your application because the algorithm itself is inefficient. It is usually much faster to [*generate* the divisors from a number's prime factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052561/849891). Prime factorization by trial division can be much quicker because we *divide out* each divisor as it is found, reducing the number being factorized and thus the amount of divisors that are tried (up to the *reduced* number's square root). For example, `12348 = 2*2*3*3*7*7*7` and no factor above `7` is tried in the process of factorization, whereas in `divs 12348` the number 12348 is divided by all numbers from `2` to `110`:

```hs
factorize n = go n (2:[3,5..])    -- or:  (go n primes)  where
   where                          --  primes = 2 :
     go n ds@(d:t)                --   filter (null.tail.factorize) [3,5..]
        | d*d > n    = [n]
        | r == 0     =  d : go q ds
        | otherwise  =      go n t
            where  (q,r) = quotRem n d
```